# Windows 10 keeps crashing on file copy disk to disk

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-transfer

I have 8TBs worth of data I am trying to copy from DISK to DISK. I reinstalled Windows 10 and that allowed me to copy 8TBs over the network initially because it was doing the same thing. But now it looks like I am plagued by the same issue again but also disk to disk. I've tried xcopy, robocopy ext..

It will copy over 6-15% and then just crash on a blue screen.

EDIT:

The drives are brand new WD REDS with no current errors are issues. I've copied files to one of the 8TBs that was in a JBOD RAID but is now SATA connected and being copied to another 8TB SATA. This is were crashing happens.

Originally, before I reinstalled the OS, copying over the network from the JBOD RAID to the 8TB that was SATA connected would crash constantly. I tried doing RAM swap but that didn't seem to help and the RAM checks from Windows kept coming back ok.

Could Windows 10 just keep corrupting itself or could the host disk(SSD) just be bad causing this?

I am attempting Acronis to clone disk to disk and the system hasn't crashed yet.

Comment: You need to note the failure message, including the hex data. If you search for the failure code you may get some insight. It's a system problem, nothing to do with the copying software. Also, check the source disc's SMART data and run a full surface check on it.

Comment: Right - one of the disks now has an unrecoverable error at the 6-15% point.

Comment: The disk to disk both are brand new wd reds. no errors. the issue also happens on other drives as well so the two drives both of which are not hosting the OS are fine from my testing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say *"I reinstalled Windows 10 and that allowed me to copy"* it sounds like your windows install is on the same drive that's giving the errors... and the drive's going bad & crashing windows along with not reading/copying.

If your goal is data recovery, I'd stop running windows from the drive and use a different system to only read & recover data before trying any SMART testing / scanning or chkdsk/fsck. It's lifetime may be almost over & I wouldn't want to spend it trying to "fix" instead of "read".

Using [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) should  have no problem with read errors, and try skipping over them initially to keep reading whatever's still good, and not running from the bad drive it *shouldn't* crash... and if it's something else in that system causing the crashes then a different system shouldn't have that problem either.

Comment: you make a good point. Boot from a live CD or something and do the copy from an OS not running on the current SSD. I should mention that the drives being read/written to are not the host OS. Both the drives being copied to and from are brand new with no errors.

Comment: Maybe it's the windows system ssd... or something else in the system, RAM's easy to test & swap. Failing on copying at 6-15% could just be a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

To rule out disk physical error run [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/) to ensure S.M.A.R.T. data is not showing errors.

After that, instead of copying the whole file/folders at once, try to copy smaller ammounts of data.

Try copying your files with [robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) instead, which is more reliable.